# How I can to use Empty method in a List in Z3Py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

In z3py I would like to use the function Empty in Z3py (https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3py_8py_source.html#l09944)

I tried to make it like this way:

```
s = Solver()

# declare a sequence of integers
iseq = Const('iseq', SeqSort(IntSort()))
solve(Empty(iseq)!= True)


# get a model and print it:
if s.check() == sat:
    print (s.model())
```

but I return me "Z3Exception: Non-sequence, non-regular expression sort passed to Empty"

I also tried to Empty(iseq) only back me a empty sequence of anything but It has not worked for me

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things going on here:

- You're declaring a solver object by `s = Solver ()`, but then you're calling the `solve` function. `solve` creates its own solver. Simply use `s.add` instead.
- `Empty` creates a sequence, given the sort. You can't call it on `iseq`. That's the error message you're getting.

I'm guessing all you're trying to say is: declare `iseq`, make sure it's not empty. You'd code that as follows:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# declare a sequence of integers
iseq = Const('iseq', SeqSort(IntSort()))

# assert it's not empty
s.add (Length(iseq) != 0)

# get a model and print it:
if s.check() == sat:
    print (s.model())
```

z3 says:

```
$ python a.py
[iseq = Unit(2)]
```

So, it gave you a model where `iseq` is the singleton sequence containing the number `2`; which is *not* empty which satisfies the constraint we posed.

Here's an example that uses `Empty` to create an empty sequence:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# Give a name to integer sequences
ISeq = SeqSort(IntSort())

# declare a sequence of integers
iseq = Const('iseq', ISeq)

# make sure it's empty!
s.add (iseq == Empty(ISeq))

# get a model and print it:
if s.check() == sat:
    print (s.model())
```

z3 says:

```
[iseq = Empty(Seq(Int))]
```

Note that z3py is essentially a functional language; once you assert something equals something else you can *not* modify that value, as you might in an imperative language like, say, Python. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I just want to try an example of Empty to better understand what works, thanks to your help I know that  Empty method generates an empty sequence, but I would like to know that I would have to put s.add (..) to generate it.

Comment: Added an example showing how to use `Empty`. Still not clear to me though what you're trying to achieve.